# Html Email: Text over Image

Tags: html

I am trying to build a email html template. I want to write text on an image and image should in center of the page. But not as background. I have tried my email template but text also comes below the image and if I use image as background it doesnt display in email. How can I write text on Image for an email html template. Please help!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
    img {
            position: relative;
        }

        p {
            position: absolute;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            top: 122px;
            left: 50px;
            width: 53%;
            font-size: 15px;
        }

        div {
            max-width: 900px;
            width: 900px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            position: relative;
        }
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <img src="http://[imageurl]" width="900">
        <p>Dear …………………………………,
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem optio voluptatibus totam commodi quos, eveniet, voluptate nesciunt voluptatum aliquid ipsam. Placeat atque nulla cupiditate, nemo unde incidunt eos accusantium laboriosam?</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you attach your email template code here.

Comment: I don't think he has paid any effort on it.

Comment: u can use CSS Layout - The position Property [ http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp ] , or add your code . we will help you

Comment: I want my text to overlap the image

Comment: So basically you want a image which is overlay on image..

Comment: I want text over an image

Answer (score 2):

just like this?

```html
<table align="center">
  <tbody>
     <tr align="center">
                                  <td height="10" valign="top" align="center" style=" background: url(http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/faiths-speak-on-referendums-17.png); background-size:400px 100px; background-position: center; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
                                      <p style="color: black; text-align: center; font-weight:100 !important; text-transform: uppercase; font-style: normal; letter-spacing: 1px; font-size: 10px; line-height:30px; font-family: 'open sans', arial, sans-serif;">Saturday 5TH MARCH, 2016</p>
                                  </td>
                              </tr>

  </tbody>
  </table>
```

[image]

adjust your image size according to your need.

hope it works.

PS: try not to use `position` property, as it will not work in **gmail** and **outlook** email engine.

check this link : [HTML Email](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)

Comment: But on copying this code to outlook mail body image disappears

Comment: check this one : https://www.campaignmonitor.com/forums/topic/3862/please-test-this-outlook-20072010-background-image-solution/

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: absolute;` on the image and the `<p>`, and set the `<p>` width to a percentage small enough to fit on the image.

See my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ahm7777/rkL4Lvet/2/) for a sample.

**Changes done on fiddle**

So I added more ideas to my original one (already explained how to get the text overlapped w/image).

1. Have the image and the `<p>` wrapped by a main container, then wrap the image on its own container.
2. After having the `<p>` overlapped with the image, make sure to set its width as short and proportional as possible to the image, and add some padding to center it more as well, justify it as well if you wish.

That's about it. It's pretty simple to create. You can check and review the fiddle a bit to see how it actually works.

Comment: question is text over image .. in your fiddle text is not over image. so change the answer. or someone vote you down for sure..

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I didn't noticed the fiddle wasn't updated. Corrected the code already and tweaked the whole code. I'll update the answer with the changes.

Comment: tried it...but still text is not overlapping image in email body.

Comment: @AntonioHernández close the image div correctly then run.. content gose out.